# Adding highcharts to existing project got unknow problem

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm trying to add highchart into an existing project

We are having this existing module like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: UsercenterComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "patients" },
      { path: "patients", component: PatientsManagementComponent },
      { path: "patients/:id/edit", component: PatientDetailsComponent },
      { path: "callcenter", component: CallcenterComponent, canDeactivate: [ConfirmDeactivateGuard] },
      { path: "monitor", component: MonitorComponent },
      // { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class UsercenterRoutingModule {
```

And I add HighChartsModule like readme said

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), HighchartsChartModule],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class UsercenterRoutingModule {
```

But in a child of child component, when I use

```html
<highcharts-chart></highcharts-chart>
```

It say

```
Error: src/app/modules/usercenter/components/monitor/monitor-card/monitor-card.component.html:3:5 - error NG8001: 'highcharts-chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'highcharts-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'highcharts-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3     <highcharts-chart></highcharts-chart>
  ~~~~~
```

Am I doing something wrong, how should I fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Import it in your feature module or root module, not routing module

Comment: I also tried to import in the App root module `export class AppModule {}`, but issue still the same

Answer (score 0):

please make sure sequence  of application flow if you have one module in angular application that is app.Module import high Chart Module

import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';

providers: [
SharedService,
SharedParamsService,
ReportService,
AuthGuard,
DecimalPipe,
{
provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES,
useFactory: () => [more, exporting, solidgauge, bullet]

please use this flow
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts